# Google Plus Interactive Share posts not showing on feed

Tags: php, javascript, google-api, google-plus

I have tried multiple things with the Google+ Interactive Share. What it does:

- Show the Google+ share screen
- Show the link and text you are currently sharing
- Make you click "Share"

As soon as this is done, the screen disappears, making the user assume that it's done. But when I go to my Google+ feed, nothing shows, not even on the App tab. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I even tested it with the example of Google themselves: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive

```
<button
  class="g-interactivepost"
  data-contenturl="https://plus.google.com/pages/"
  data-contentdeeplinkid="/pages"
  data-clientid="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-prefilltext="Engage your users today, create a Google+ page for your business."
  data-calltoactionlabel="CREATE"
  data-calltoactionurl="http://plus.google.com/pages/create"
  data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/pages/create">
Tell your friends
</button>
```

And that doesn't even work. Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Can you check the JavaScript Console in your browser, and post any errors that you are seeing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "data-contenturl" and the "data-calltoactionurl" must be the same. That's why it didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

The "data-contenturl" and the "data-calltoactionurl" must have the same host and protocol.
In your case use both with HTTPS or HTTP. Different paths are OK.